# how to make a circular indicator widget as dots as a widget in my flutter app?

Tags: android, dart, flutter, viewpagerindicator

I am looking to create an indicator widget for my pageview app, that means that It will be inside my widget tree.

What I have remarked is that When I use
PageViewIndicator class, it's automatically placed either in bottom or centre but when I place it in the center, for example, it hides my fields thing that I don't want, so what do you think?

I have used This

```dart
PageIndicatorContainer(
  pageView: PageView(
    children: customWidgetLists,
    controller: controller,
  ),
  align: IndicatorAlign.Center,
  length: 4,
  indicatorSpace: 20.0,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
  indicatorColor: Colors.white,
  indicatorSelectorColor: Colors.blue,
  shape: IndicatorShape.circle(size: 12),
  // shape: IndicatorShape.roundRectangleShape(size: Size.square(12),cornerSize: Size.square(3)),
  // shape: IndicatorShape.oval(size: Size(12, 8)),
}
```

Everything works fine, just I want the dots to be in the centre of the screen and not cover the other widgets because it did.

Comment: Hello, please be a bit more specific about your question and add a code example (with screenshots if you like) showing your problems.

Comment: okey , I did add some code and more explanation of the problem. thansk in advance